# Why does my screen flicker only in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, display

I have a HP 4530S laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. After five to ten minutes of usage, my screen starts flickering. Check the screenshot below.

I have also another OS installed (Fedore 13), but there I never get this flickering.

What could be the possible cause of the screen flickering only appearing in Windows 7? I am using the latest drivers from the HP site.

[image]

I am not using any external monitor, it's the LCD of my laptop.

EDIT: I only got this error when I am on battery, when on direct power I did't get this error.

Comment: Sorry, I know I'm not supposed to ask a question, but just a quick one? How did you solve your problem? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like hardware failing, either the graphics card or monitor electronics. In laptop those two obviously are tied. The only thing you can do to it yourself is to check that no part of the system overheats; but most likely that only postpones the inevitable, ie. replacing the hardware is in order sooner or later.

For reasons why it only happens in Windows.. start by checking the refresh rates; if Windows tries to use higher refresh rate, it might make a soon-to-be-failing-totally hardware beyond the point of failure. Temperatures of course can also differ between OSes, because you run different amounts of eye candy. Also the exact pattern of loading the hardware varies due to different drivers etc.

Answer (score -1):

Possible Solution according to what I know,is to adjust the screen refresh rate. Or Disassemble the display unit and replace the inverter