# Why does my screen flicker and my laptop crash?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 7 on it. Every so often the screen goes exactly like the one in this picture ([Why does my screen flicker only in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/324305/why-does-my-screen-flicker-only-in-windows-7)) and freezes. Nothing works and I need to switch off the laptop manually. I've run all sorts of hardware tests with help from the Dell hardware support team. They found nothing and say it's a software problem.

This usually happens once a week but on a very hot day recently it happened five times within 8 hours. So I'm wondering if it could be overheating. The Windows refresh rate is set to 60 and the screen resolution is set to 1366x768. If it is overheating, what can I do to solve the problem?

And what kind of software problem could it be? And how to fix it?

Comment: What model is your dell laptop?

Comment: ALso, how old is your laptop?  When you're using it, do you have it laying flat on a table, or in your lap?  It's possible that dust/hair may have collected in the heat sink and fan inside, or the way you're using it may be blocking the airflow (Most laptops are/were designed to be laid down on a flat surface)

Comment: That kind of visual image you linked to is what happens when the video ram is too hot (or too overclocked) the memory that the screen buffer is displaying from is corrupting. Anything is possible (for it to be software) but it is not likely at all. Add your specific symptoms and interval, and it is 99.8% likely to be hardware and overheating.

Comment: It's about 18 months, but this problem has happened from the first month. As it was only occasionally, I didn't bother. I use it on a table.

Comment: It's a Dell N5110. I think it is overheating. It just happened again and the temperature on HWMonitor went close to 70... Any advice on fixing the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Internally , you disassemble , check for blockages, check dust, fans, heat syncs of all types, replace thermal paste. Basically you tech what an assembly line doesn't have time to do. Externally, adjust any provided soft options to increase fan speed, in bios/uefi or any provided software util. Updated bioses like dtmland said. For desktops both AMD and Nivida have software options for fan speed. 3rd party "SpeedFan" software  that a user can set motherboard fan speeds the way they want. Speedfan doesnt work on many of the laptops, chipset not supported or blocked from chaging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my screen flicker only in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/324305/why-does-my-screen-flicker-only-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that you say its worse on hotter days, my guess is that either your specific unit is faultly, or their is a fault in product design.

Neither is out of the question, I had a Dell laptop that had [similar video problems](http://en.community.dell.com/dell-blogs/direct2dell/b/direct2dell/archive/2008/07/25/nvidia-gpu-update-for-dell-laptop-owners.aspx). This [isn't the first time Dell has had this problem](http://hothardware.com/News/Dell-Issues-NVIDIA-GPU-Update-To-Laptop-Owners/):

> You have the option of updating your BIOS, which will likely turn up
>   your fan speed and potentially make your notebook slightly louder, in
>   hopes that you don't have issues down the road

Answer (score 2):

That does not look like a software problem at all, but more like you mentioned yourself, a overheating problem.
Either your graphics card, RAM and/or your CPU could be overheating. I would put my money on your graphics card and you could put it all to a test.

### CPU and RAM test

Download [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/hwmonitor/1.23-setup.exe) and [Prime95 (x64)](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=205) / [Prime95 (x32)](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=103) and install them both.
Start up HWMonitor and check the temperatures under your the name of your motherboard and graphics card. It looks something like this:

[image: HWMonitor]

**NOTE**
Not all graphics cards support this, so you might not be able to see the temperature.

While having `CPUID` open, fire up `Prime95`.
Make sure that *Blend* is marked and click OK to start testing. This will torture your CPU and RAM, so go back to `HWMonitor` and monitor the CPU temperatures, if it's getting really high (70+) then you should be worried.

### GPU test

Start by downloaded [Furmark](http://www.geeks3d.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=352) and install it and fire it up.

The program should identify your graphics card and you should have to *"burn-in" buttons*, click the one labelled 15 min (You should not run it longer than this). This test really gets your GPU high temperature, so be sure keep an eye on `HWMonitor` and you could get the same flickering as on your image.

Comment: It just happened again twice. I had just downloaded HWmonitor. When I switched the laptop back on and opened HWmonitor the temperaturer for Intel Core i5 were almost 70 and the fan was working like mad. I'll do the other tests. Many thanks.