# Colored lines on monitor with freeze mostly on video playback

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, motherboard

My PC is showing colored lines and freezes and restarts moments after I starts playing some video. I have also seen this happening when I open an image. It will show the problem the instant I start video playback. I thought it was some problem with the driver but the lines are visible even on the bios boot screen when restart.

My hardware is as follows :
intel core i5 750 CPU,
ASUS ATI Radeon HD 5450 graphics card,
ASUS P7P55D motherboard,
2Gb Cosair DDR3 ram sticks x 2,
2 SATA hard drives,

It could be problem with Motherboard, video card, RAM or drivers. I am looking for some tips to identify the component that caused.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your graphics card is overheating.  This can cause lines and artifacts on the display.  You should use a monitoring tool like [GPUTemp](http://www.gputemp.com/).  It could be the thermal paste on your GPU is not properly transferring the heat to your GPU fan.

Comment: I will check that.. but mine is ASUS 0dB basic card with no fan but just a heat sink.

Comment: The thermal paste and the heat sink might not be properly set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your computer's CPU heat sink is probably caked with dust. I would purchase a can of compressed air and blow the heat sink out.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a overheating and I would suggest that you test your hardware.

I've made a post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/623291/why-does-my-screen-flicker-and-my-laptop-crash/623309#623309) on how to stress-test your CPU, RAM and GPU, it should pinpoint where the problem lies.